# Highlight Line on GotFocus

Tags: c#, wpf, line

I want to highlight a Line if it was clicked. Like a TreeViewItem is highlighted while it is selected or got focused (It seems, that there is a diffrence - While it is focused(and selected) its Highlight-Color is blue, if it only got selected and lost focused its grayish.).
I tried to catch the Gotfocus Event of Line without knowing which property I want to change, but it is not even firing(Though Focusable = true).
I got the MouseDown event firing(which i primarly don't want to use for this) and still don't know which property to change. Msdn and Google returns nothing senseful.
Any Ideas?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this now.

for example

```
 <Path Data="M101,42 L380,76" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="35" 
    Margin="101,42,243,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="Path_MouseEnter" Name="myLine"/>
```

and c#

```
private void Path_MouseEnter(object sender, 
System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}
```

please check now :)

Comment: Why shold I use a textblock and use its GotFocus if I want to get the GotFocus of a Line? Textblock and Line do not even got sth in common while Textblock inherits from Controls and Line from Shape...

Comment: I misunderstood your question. My bad.

Comment: Look my comment on seond answer, I explained the problem furthermore ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use style and triggers for this kind of work. You won't need any code only XAML will work. Create a trigger that will fire once the `mouse down = true` and inside that trigger change the color of line or it's background or whatever you want

see [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html) for basics about Triggers.

Comment: That's true. But there's still the problem, that i don't know which property to change. I already looked up UIElement and didn't find any useful to simulate that highlighting part (e.g. of a TreeViewItem). Background and Foreground do not work neither.

Comment: Can you encapsulate that line inside another control like stackpanel or something. Then change the background of stackpanel and it will seems like that line is hi-lighted?

Comment: Good Idea. Checkout Stroke Property it seems it can outline the line

Comment: I gonna explain the highlight part: If u Select a TreeViewItem - its Background change to blue, while the Text does not affected by. I want sth similar to this for Line. Change the surrounding of a line while the Lines' color does not get affected by.Stackpanel or sth else above isn't a really good idea cause I got MANY lines. But i will look, if there is sth like an outline in 'stroke'

Comment: create lines surrounding you line with same color and after your line got focus change surrounding lines color.

Comment: Well Stroke does not got anything useful for my problem. And create Lines around the primary seems a lil bit ridicoulus for me to solve this problem!? I think, the solution of this problem will end in sth. 'like' a panel. I need a container which changes its background if its content got focused. The Problem is, that panels like Stackpanel got a positioning of y1=0,y2 = 0 while my line got y1 =0,y2=xyz.